# Proportional editing snapping not working

Tags: modeling

sorry if the title is confusing but I'm beginning to learn blender and I'm on video 4 of the blender guru donut guide and trying to make icing dribble but snapping wont work and when i try to model the icing it clips through

https://youtu.be/Ou_uAuHxxuY (sorry for the horrible quality)

Comment: Two things in your video: Did you turn off the Cage option on the Solidify modifier so that you could see what you are doing (https://youtu.be/R1isb0x4zYw?t=65) and did you turn on the Project Individual Elements on the Snapping menu (https://youtu.be/R1isb0x4zYw?t=252)? The links point to the times in the video where it is explained. You are using version 3.6.5 so you need to select 'Face Nearest' on the Snapping menu as he explains in the first comment below the video..

Comment: Pointing at tutorial on YouTube does not mean that everyone has seen it. The version of Blender could be older than the one you are using. Check for changes between versions. For best results, please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Make sure to edit your post and include screenshots showing the problem or write down steps that lead to the issue.

Comment: @RumenBelev I think I've covered all the issues that the questioner has, including the Blender version number difference between his one and the one Andrew was using in his tutorial. For what it's worth, the link to it is [here](https://youtu.be/R1isb0x4zYw).

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your answer. It is just a good practice to provide a clear explanation within the post itself. This way future readers will get the questions and answers without having have to leave the page and visit other websites following links that may expire.